# Can we view our app's statistics (sales, etc.) on iTunes Connect in windows?

Tags: windows, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to access iTunes Connect on a Windows machine? I don't want to upload apps, but only to view the statistics of my apps (sales, ratings, and so on) and also maybe change the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - its just a website. Though I suggest using Chrome/Safari. IE had some bugs back in the day at least

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, it's a web page. But I would suggest you look into http://www.appannie.com. It's a much nicer interface.